# Run HTML scripts in Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to run HTML scripts in an iOS application? I want to send an email using a script when a `UISwitch` us on, because I have to send encoded data that I do not want the user to accidentally modify. I have an option in my app preferences that will allow users to send debugging data to me so I can fix the app, kind of like what Adobe did in their mobile Photoshop app. The best way I can think of doing this is to use the HTML script below:

```
<a href="mailto: subject= &body="></a>
```

Also, will my app be rejected if I include that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MFMailComposeViewController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

And send your debug data an attachment (addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:) so the user can't modify it. The user can't modify attachments, only delete them, so warn the user to not delete the attachment.

Using an HTML link like that will still open the mail app and let the user edit the message before sending.